# How to manage shopping cart in UITableView with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, shopping-cart

My **self.totalPriceLabel** show's total price of all shop Product.It works fine but when is i scroll the `cell` the go off screen due to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` `self.totalPriceLabel` gets incorrect value.i am saving value in array which is stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell : CartCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cartCell") as! CartCell!
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = CartCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cartCell")
        }

        cell?.itemCount.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell?.clipsToBounds = true

        cell?.itemCount.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell?.itemCount.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell?.itemMinus.tag = indexPath.row
        cell?.itemPlus.tag = indexPath.row
        cell?.itemDelete.tag = indexPath.row

        let key = self.readArray[indexPath.row]

         cell?.itemCount.text = String("\(key.allValues[0])")
        let tupleVar = getProductNameFromCharacter(String("\(key.allKeys[0])"))
        cell?.itemName.text = tupleVar.tempName
        cell?.itemPrice.text = String("\(tupleVar.price)")

        //Actual Logic
        let tempCount = key.allValues[0] as! Double
        let nextItemPrice = (cell!.itemPrice.text! as NSString).doubleValue * tempCount
        self.totalPriceLabel.text = String("\((self.totalPriceLabel.text! as NSString).doubleValue + nextItemPrice)")


        return cell!

    }
```

Issue: As scroll `cell` getting wrong values.for `self.totalPriceLabel`.

> self.totalPriceLabel.text = String("((self.totalPriceLabel.text! as
>   NSString).doubleValue + nextItemPrice)")

How to get `cell` value which just goes out off screen ? how to fix this issue due to scrolling?

Comment: I feel its wrong approach to manage `totalPriceLabel`, you should take your `totalPrice` in one variable and you need to update the label text when your variable value got updated.

Comment: @amorbytes. Yes i taken single variable totalPriceLabel on bottom of viewcontroller's view.it is not in Tableview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cellForRowAtIndexpath is the wrong place to do that calculation. You are assuming that iOS will call this function once for each cell. This isn't the case.  This function is called to display a single cell. It could very well get called multiple times for the same cell as you scroll up and down.

You should be updating that total when you add or remove items from the underlying data (self.readArray).

Also, add code to change the total when the quantity button is tapped.

If you want more specific help, post the entire controller.